# How to trigger SendGrid single send from API

Tags: sendgrid

I'm able to create single send for a segment from API, but it is not being sent and its status is shown as "draft"

as "send_at" (says that it must be a datetime in the future) is optional and also in the single send intro says that single send can be sent immediately or scheduled for a time in the future I assumed that I shouldn't set any value to this property to send the emails immediately. these are the single sends I have created using API:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The single send will be in draft mode until it is scheduled.

Specifically this endpoint needs to be hit using that Single Send id: **/v3/marketing/singlesends/{sendgrid_single_send_id}/schedule**
With the send_at specified as a date in the future